Not able to show a pdf / image from binary data in MSSQL using PDO LOB
I go MSSQL database which contains attachments - most of them are PDFs. I want to create simple website, that will display attachment after clicking a button. I got main website prepared (there are records with attachments' titles and a link fo the other page, that is supposed to just show the attachment in the new tab).
I've been using PDO as I heard that is secure and pretty simple.
My query '$sql' for sure returns one row (I have checked that by simply doing var_dump() of the FetchAll()).
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$id]);

    $stmt->bindColumn(10,$lob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $stmt->bindColumn(11, $attachment, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256); 
    $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);
    $lobContent = stream_get_contents($lob);


    $ext = substr(strrchr($attachment, '.'),1); 



      
       header("Content-Type: Application/pdf");
     
        // fpassthru($lob) shows some weird stuff that looks like memory leak
         echo $lobContent; 

Any ideas what Am I doing wrong here? If I try to use fpassthru() it show me some garbage, I mean it looks like memory leak or something, there are some parts of the code, that is not on my website and is not in the database...
I have checked if the query result isn't empty, tried to just fetchAll() the data I got but as told above, got very unexpected behaviour.

This post provides a solution to similar problem using SQLSRV driver. Which driver (and version) do you use to connect to SQL Server?

@Zhorov SELECT
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583456) - 14.0.2037.2 (X64)  Nov  2 2020 19:19:59  Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: )

This is the SQL Server version. How exactly do you create a connection ($pdo = new PDO(...);)?

'$dsn = "sqlsrv:server=address;
database=name of db;Encrypt=0";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";'
And then:
'$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);'

I managed to get the data in the browser. Now I'm failing to convert the code into the pdf.
The code:
$attachment = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 9,
SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR));
//header("Content-Type: Application/pdf");
fpassthru($attachment);
Once im uncommenting the Content-Type header, it says "Failed to open document".
Ther beggining of the output looks like this: 3C3F7068700A2F2A0A20202020436F7079726....

If you want a solution to your specific problem, you need to edit the question and include all relevant information - the table structure, sample data, your current code and the problems you face, the expected results.

I have managed to solve my problem. It turned out that weird output isn'tany memory leak - it was just the contnent of the document that I was getting the binary from. After finding it out I have tried few things and the milestone was changing the PDO connection to
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $conninfo); 
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params); 
if ( sqlsrv_fetch( $stmt ) )  
{ 
$attachment = sqlsrv_get_field( $stmt, 10,   
SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY));  

header("Content-Type: Application/pdf");  

fpassthru($attachment);
  
}  

I was able to open the pdf and images from databse in my browser, using binaries saved in the db!
Hope this helps anyone in the future tho I know, it is a workaround.
